# How to authenticate UIViewController for Facebook API

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically if i use the code below in the delegate where i initialised the facebook login button provided by the facebook SDK, it works(enters successful and prints out the details). The delegate class which I create and use the button is called: "LoginviewController"

LoginviewController.m:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
            NSLog(@"user info: %@", result);
        }  else {
            NSLog(@"Failed");
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
        }
    }];
```

However when I tried using this in another viewcontroller called profileView, it doesn't work(always says failed) regardless of an active session ! So my wild guess is that i need a way of authenticating this view so i can access the users facebook info?

Please what am i doing wrong ? Thanks alottt !

p.s This is how i use to check if the user is already logged in so it should go to the profile view:

DViewController.m:

```
LoginViewController *viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    ProfileViewController *profileviewController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];

    if (!FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
    {
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.3;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:profileviewController animated:NO];

    }else{
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.3;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    }
```

Again Thanks a million ! :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: here is no way/need to authenticate your view, you can just authenticate your application.
My first guess to solve your problem is try to use this component to log your user in:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

And use this callback function to handle the user login:

```
// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
  self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
  self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
}
```

Don't forget to add these lines to your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

        // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
        BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

        // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

        return wasHandled;
    }
```

Afterwards in an other view you can check if the user is logged in with the following method:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
{
    //.....
}
```

Take care to store your FBLoginView (as a strong property) if you want to log the user out.
i hope it solves your problem, cheers